# Returning to Japan with an expired re-entry permit

Tags: visas, japan, italian-citizens, entry-permit

I had obtained a Japanese work visa, but quit my job and left Japan for over a year. When I left, I received a re-entry permit on my passport (I am Italian).

I am now thinking of visiting Japan for a brief trip, but the re-entry permit has expired (it's still attached to my passport) and my work visa was only valid for the duration of my employment.

What would happen if I go back to Japan?

Comment: Ciao, **the re-entry permit has expired** - then you need a **new tourist visa**, that's it.

Comment: @Fattie thanks!! That's what I thought but I didn't want to risk being tortured by a samurai upon arrival :O heheh

Comment: **LOL** @DaniG2k - right.  You know, as someone mentions below the airlines use "Timotic" so, in fact, they would not let you board even at this end when heading to Japan.  Prego!

Comment: @Fattie No, because Italian citizens can visit Japan visa-free for business or tourism for up to 90 days.

Comment: I think that's what @Fattie meant by a new tourist visa - it's issued on the spot when you enter the country.

Answer (score 3):

As you are Italian and do not need a visa before traveling to Japan, you should be able to just get in a plane and travel to Japan, just as if you had never been in Japan before.

If you fear they see the old visa and re-entry permit and assume you are coming back to work again, you can take proof of your current work and your ties to your home country, just like you would prepare to take to an interview for a visa.
It should not be needed but it will give you rest of mind.

You can check your need for visa in the sites airlines use, to check visa. Here is a link for the [Timatic site](https://www.timaticweb.com/) and [here one for an airline site](https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/) I like to use, goes to the same database.

Answer (score 1):

If your nationality requires visa for tourist purposes first thing that can happen your airline prohibit to board, there will be no refund.

If you get to airplane and then to Japan you will be stopped at papers check and then forced to leave Japan. Very likely your airline will be obligated to take you back and then they force you to pay super extra price for return ticket.

Comment: What if I do not require a visa for tourism?

Comment: Then you may simply go, and your previous re-entry permit is irrelevant (it's irrelevant anyway regardless).

Comment: The question was edited a few minutes after you posted, to clarify that the asker is Italian. Italians don't need a visa for business/tourism visits to Japan of up to 90 days.